# how to replace space with %20 in java

Tags: android

I have a string which contains space like this

```
https://storage101.dfw1.clouddrive.com/v1/MossoCloudFS_e872fd49-0dab-4502-8689-d126b9552334/Sales Force Technologies/360/SMC_C1_M1_Agile_Overview_and_need_for_Agile.mp4?
```

How to replace spaces in this string with %20 so that it should display

> Sales%20Force%20Technologies

I want to replace only space not other special characters.

Comment: `Uri.parse()` should take care of the encoding

Answer (score 4):

Use the `String.replaceAll()` method.

```
String newUrlString = urlString.replaceAll(" ", "%20");
```

Beware though that the first parameter is a regex expression, so if you want to split with a . (or any special regex char for that matter) you would have to do this \.